# the buzzer stops sounding after a few seconds

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

Sorry, I'm not fluent in English.
I beg your help
I made an arduino uno project where the buzzer only turns on for 2 seconds after the light turns on. Even though the light is still on I want the buzzer to turn off after 2 seconds. I have tried several methods but I still fail.I use sensor ldr here.
can you guys help me?

```
    if( sensorValue <= 25 && lastBuzzer == 0)
   {
    lastBuzzer = millis();
   }
   if(sensorValue <= 25)
  {
    if (millis() - lastBuzzer < 1000L)
    {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    delay(100);
    
  }
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
    lastBuzzer = 0;
    
  }
```

Comment: There is no light or 2-second-interval in your code and it won't behave like you want at all. Please post a full minimal example so we have something to work with.

Comment: `still fail` does not describe what happens ... please edit your post with a description of observed behavior

Comment: If there is even one `sensorValue > 25` it will stop beeping and is armed again for the next beep if it goes <= 25 -- you might want to average sensor values to protect against outliers. Did you put in some `Serial.println()` statements to see all `sensorValue` values that it processes?

Comment: You need to study https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay as that gives you a way to run two timer events simultaneously. One can blink your LED, the other can sound your buzzer for two seconds.

Comment: At least give us a circuitry showing what you're doing or what you want to do.